# k-means analysis: how to convert data into numeric?

Tags: r, k-means

I want to perform a k-means analysis in R. For that I need numeric data. I tried the following

```
unlist(pca)
as.numeric(pca)

lapply(pca,as.numeric(pca))
```

pca is just "normal" Principal Component Analysis data, showed in a plot (with fviz_pca_ind() function).

By the way, when I try to run the k-means analysis, it gives me "list object cannot be coerced to type double". That is why I thought to turn everything into numeric.

How to convert the pca-data into numeric?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example. It's really unclear what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost correct

```
lapply(pca,as.numeric)
```

`as.numeric` is a function and therefore an object. You need to pass it to `lapply()` as an object and therefore without the quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you, but it shows: Error in lapply(pca_individ_cafru, as.numeric) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Yeah, I already expected this reply. If you want us to help you, please post your data using `dput(pca)` - that means if this is not to big.

Answer (score 0):

Most pca objects should return you a list, and you should show which package or function is used to perform the pca, so we can see what's in the list

For example, if you use `prcomp`, it returns a list of eigenvectors / loadings ($rotation) and principal components ($x). I suppose you are trying to do k-means on the principal componets, and you can do it like:

```
# perform pca
pca = prcomp(USArrests,scale=TRUE)
# we call out the PCs using pca$x
# and kmeans
kmeans_clus = kmeans(pca$x,3)
## plot 
# define colors
COLS = c("#65587f","#f18867","#e85f99")
plot(pca$x[,1:2],col=COLS[kmeans_clus$cluster],pch=20)
legend("topright",fill=COLS,legend=1:3,horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]